# If $(x_{2k+4})$ and $(x_{2k+5})$ converge to the same limit, is $(x_k)$ also converging, and to the same limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Say there is a sequence $(x_n)$ and one knows only two subsequences of that sequence, one containing the terms $(x_{2k+4})$ and the other containing the terms $(x_{2k+5})$.

If both of them converge to the same limit, will the sequence converge and if it does, will it converge to the same limit?

I have seen all the similar questions on Maths.S.E. but none of them had a rigorous proof on this idea.

Comment: This has been asked hundreds of time. If literally *none* of the answers that already exist satisfy your requirements for a "rigorous proof", say that, link to them, and explain why they're not rigorous enough. Otherwise, this question is going to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I found out the typo in my question but could not correct it at that time due to slow network .Now I have corrected it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The new question isn't very different. Just apply the theorem to $(x_{n+4})$, it's exactly the same thing ($\lim x_n = l \iff \lim x_{n+4} = l$).

Comment: @Aniket Modifying the question after answers were posted should be avoided. And you did it *twice*... :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Proof: let $x$ be the common limit and let $O$ be any neighbourhood of $x$ (or use epsilons in a metric setting...). As the subsequence $(x_{2n})_n$ converges to $x$, there exists $N_1$ such that $n > N_1$ implies $x_{2n} \in O$, and also there exists $N_2$ such that $n > N_2$ implies $x_{2n+1} \in O$.

Let $n > M = 2\max{N_1,N_2}  +1 $ Then if $n$ is even, say $n = 2k$, we have that $k > N_1$ (otherwise $k \le N_1 \rightarrow 2k = n \le 2N_1 \le 2\max(N_1,N_2) <  M$, contradiction) and so $x_{2k} = x_n \in O$. If $n$ is odd, say $n = 2k+1$, then $ k > N_2$ (or $k \le N_2$, so $ n = 2k+1 \le 2N_2 + 1 \le 2\max(N_1,N_2)+1 = M$, contradiction) so $x_{2k+1} = x_n \in O$ as well. All $n$ are either even or odd, so always $x_n \in O$ for $ n > M$. So $M$ works to show convergence.

Comment: I found out the typo in my question but could not correct it at that time due to slow network .Now I have corrected it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: The subsequences of $2k+4$ and $2k+5$ are just the same as the even and odd terms, from 6 onwards (fill in $k=1,2\ldots$ and see for yourself), so the same proof applies, provided $M > 6$ which we can assume anyway.

Comment: Oh thanks! got it...

Answer (score 1):

Yes the sequence will converge to that limit since the subsequences $u_{2n}$ and $u_{2n+1}$ contains all the terms of $u_n$.
Even if you change the question, it is easy to show that $u_{2n+4=2(n+2)}$ and $u_{2n+5=2(n+2)+1}$ are subsequences which contain all terms of $u_n, n\geq 6$.

Comment: I found out the typo in my question but could not correct it at that time due to slow network .Now I have corrected it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what does it mean to say that a sequence $a_n$ converges to $L$?  It means that given any positive $\epsilon$ we can find an integer $M=M(\epsilon)$ such that $n>M\implies |a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

So...pick $\epsilon>0$.  By your assumptions we can find two constants $M_{even},M_{odd}$ such that $$2n>M_{even} \implies |x_{2n}-L|<\epsilon\;\;\&\;\;2n+1>M_{odd}\implies |x_{2n+1}-L|<\epsilon$$

But then, letting $M=\max(M_{even},M_{odd})$ we see that 
$$n>M\implies |x_n-L|<\epsilon$$ and we are done.

Comment: I found out the typo in my question but could not correct it at that time due to slow network .Now I have corrected it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you are in a metric space $(E,d)$. $(x_{2k})$ converges to some limit, say $x$ means that $\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists N_{\epsilon}:\,\forall k\geq N_{\epsilon}:d(x_{2k},x)<\epsilon$. We have also, $\forall\epsilon>0\,\exists N'_{\epsilon}:\,\forall k\geq N'_{\epsilon}:d(x_{2k+1},x)<\epsilon$. Let now define $K_{\epsilon}=\text{max}\{N\epsilon,N'_{\epsilon}\}$. Then, $\forall k\geq K_{\epsilon},\,d(x,x_{2k})<\epsilon$ and $d(x,x_{2k+1})<\epsilon$, so that $\forall k\geq K_{\epsilon},\,d(x,x_{k})<\epsilon$ and the sequence $(x_{k})$ converges to $x$.

Comment: I found out the typo in my question but could not correct it at that time due to slow network .Now I have corrected it. Sorry for the inconvenience.